# Dishwasher water backup

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

My dishwasher empties just fine But, a day or 3 later, I have water backed up into it. How do I fix this myself? Please be very precise, I am a retired lady whose plumbing experience was replacing washers back in the day.

Comment: Are there any factors that occur before the water backup?  It's tough to be precise w/o much detail from you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Check the drain hose

A dishwasher normally requires either an **air gap** or a **high hose loop**. Both are ways to make sure that water can get out of the dishwasher but can't easily get back in. In the case of an air gap, if it breaks you will have a mess. But in the case of a high hose loop, if it falls down (or was never installed correctly in the first place) then water can come into the dishwasher from using the sink.

A high hose loop is normally a flexible hose that goes from the dishwasher up to just underneath the counter, but at a minimum it must be above the bottom of the sink, and then goes down to either the disposal (most disposals have a special connection for dishwashers) or to the sink drain pipe just before the trap.

If you are not sure how your dishwasher hose is connected, post a picture.